# Регулярное выражение для строки с разными разделителями

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

С регулярками всегда были проблемы, поэтому буду признателен за помощь :)
Имеется строка:

```
"test, test2, test@mail.ru, 1234$, \"Test3, Test4\", \"Test5, Test6\""
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как будет выглядеть регулярка для получения вот такого результата

```
test
test2
test@mail.ru
1234$
Test3, Test4
Test5, Test6
```

Заранее всем большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Это CSV? Тогда используйте какой-нибудь csv-парсер. Поиск по термину csv поможет быстро найти решение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, все верно. Пробовал CsvHelper но как я понял, он не может прочитать строки такого формата. Режет данные, например, у нас есть Test3, Test4, а парсится только Test3. Если знаете как это сделать с его помощью, буду рад вашему ответу :)

Comment: Сперва задайте вопрос по CSV. Этот ваш вопрос - по регуляркам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте это: `(\\"(?<chunk>.+?)\\"|(?!\s)(?<chunk>[^\\",]+)(?<!\s))`. Искомое в группе `chunk`.

Предполагается, что внутри литерала не в кавычках не будет обратных слэшей и кавычек. `(?!\s)` и `(?<!\s)` предотвращают захват лишних пробелов в незакавыченные литералы, пропуская пробелы внутри них.

[Демонстрация](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%5c%22%28%3f%3cchunk%3e.%2b%3f%29%5c%5c%22%7c%28%3f!%5cs%29%28%3f%3cchunk%3e%5b%5e%5c%5c%22%2c%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3c!%5cs%29%29&i=test%2c+test2%2c+test%40mail.ru%2c+1234%24%2c+%5c%22Test3%2c+Test4%5c%22%2c+%5c%22Test5%2c+Test6%5c%22).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Но у меня почему-то подчеркивает chunk, можно посмотреть вот тут https://regex101.com/r/GQxl9p/1

Comment: Потому что в PERL-совместимых регулярных выражениях имена групп не должны повторяться, если не поставить опцию  `(?J)`: https://regex101.com/r/GQxl9p/2.

В .Net — можно использовать повторяющиеся группы, но см. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508406/6632736.